# angular 2 установить фон через атрибут style или ngStyle

Tags: angular2

Не получается установить фон, который получаю с массива объектов:

```
<article *ngFor="let item of itemRow" [ngStyle]="{ 'background-image': {{item.value}} }">
```

Как быть?

Comment: <article *ngFor="let item of itemRow" [ngStyle]="{ 'background-image': {{item.value}} }">

Comment: [style.background]="{{item.background}}" так тоже не получается ....

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax [style.background-image]="'url(' + photo + ')'"

Comment: Огромное спасибо)))

Comment: у Вас получилось?

Comment: @валератернавский Не пишите комментарии, изменяйте вопрос [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/688048/edit).

Comment: Вот то что вы предыдущее показали пошло [style.background]="item.background"

Answer (score 0):

У вас ошибка в синтаксисе: `item.value` не требуется обрамлять в двойные фигурные скобки